# Laravel - Name from foreign key doesn't show in my blade

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm making a project where I use the foreign key from a shop in products. The foreign key works but when I want to show it in my blade by using `$product->shop_id->shop_name`, it gives a blank spot. My foreign key is named 'shop_id'.[Product page without shop name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VJnc.png)

**This is my code:**

ProductController:

```
public function getProduct()
{
   $products = DB::table('products')->inRandomOrder()->simplePaginate(15);

   return view('product', ['products' => $products]);
}
```

product.blade.php

```
 @foreach($products as $product)
            <div class="column4 ">
                <div class="box ProductPage">
                    <img src="{{$product->product_image}}" alt="" class="image image-full"/>
                    <h3>{{$product->product_name}}</h3>
                    <p>Inhoud: {{$product->product_volume}}</p>
                    <p><u>€{{$product->product_price}}</u></p>
                    <p>Winkel:{{$product->shop_id->shop_name}}</p>
                </div>
                <a href="{{$product->product_url}}" class="button button-small">Bekijk product</a>
            </div>
```

Product Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     *
     */
    protected $table = 'products';

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     *
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_name', 'product_volume', 'product_price', 'product_url', 'product_image',
    ];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
     *
     *
     */

    public function shop()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Shop', 'shop_id');
    }

}
```

Shop model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Shop extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     *
     */
    protected $table = 'shops';

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     *
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'shop_name',
    ];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'shop_id')->withDefault();
    }


}
```

Comment: change from `$product->shop_id` to `$product->shop`

Comment: What is the primary key column name on `shops` and `products` table? Is it default `id` or you have changed it to something else? @daan-verweij

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your provided wrong namespace and keys in your relationship declaration. You must change as in example below to be able use these methods

`Product.php`

```
public function shop()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Shop::class, 'shop_id', 'shop_id');
}
```

After that you can access product shop using

```
<p>Winkel: {{ $product->shop->shop_name }}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it still doesn't show the shop name in the blade.

Comment: Maybe `shop_name` isn't right column name? Does product have valid shop in database? Show me a your github repo to see more files

Comment: This is my [shop table](https://paste.pics/1eb06a92b46c7ca95b2d488123427f9e) and this is my [product table](https://paste.pics/d980c268da1dc11f4c4feb07343b965c)

Comment: I updated `shop` relationship, apply these changes and now everything should work. Mark question as best if it will be working. BTW, you naming your table columns not by convention so laravel can't automatically solve foreign key and owner key names